# Npm start cannot find module './utils/verifyPackageTree'

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I created a react app using
`npx create-react-app skling9`

I could start it yesterday using `npm start`
but now I just cannot start it

I am getting this error...

```
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:936
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module './utils/verifyPackageTree'
Require stack:
- /home/skul/Documents/web/node/skling9/node_modules/react-scripts/scripts/start.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/skul/Documents/web/node/skling9/node_modules/react-scripts/scripts/start.js:26:27)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1105:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:77:12) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    '/home/skul/Documents/web/node/skling9/node_modules/react-scripts/scripts/start.js'
  ]
```

This is my package.json file

```json
{
  "name": "skling9",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.3.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "react": "^18.1.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.1.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.3.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-scripts/scripts/start.js",
    "build": "node node_modules/react-scripts/scripts/build.js",
    "test": "node node_modules/react-scripts/scripts/test.js",
    "eject": "node node_modules/react-scripts/scripts/eject.js"
  },

  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Some of the other questions on stack overflow just suggested many things but none of them helped and neither is google search...

I am new to node and cannot understand anything... please help

Answer (score 0):

I uninstalled node modules and ran
`npm install` and `npm start dev` it works :-)